# Using lsof to track files open by script that is run through the command line

Tags: bash, process, lsof

I know that I can use `lsof` to track files opened by running processes, process groups, users, and those open in specific directories, among other example. However I am curious to see if I can trap files that were opened by a program that is not always running, but runs only for a limited amount of time, such as a bash script or a Ruby program.

For instance, imagine I can run my Ruby tests by doing `rspec` in my Rails directory. How can I get a list of ALL files open by `rspec`?

In other words, how can make lsof trap open files from a process in real time? Visually, it make look like `lsof rspec`, where `lsof` execs `rspec` and records all open files.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be looking for the `strace` program, which can trace and log system calls.  For example, I can ask for a list of files opened by the `grep` command like this:

```
strace -e trace=open,openat grep something M* > /dev/null
```

The `-e trace=open,openat` option tells `strace` that we're only interested in those two system calls.

I've redirected the output of `grep` to `/dev/null` here to avoid cluttering the output; you could also send the output of `strace` to a file using the `-o` option.

Assuming I have the files `MANIFEST.in`, `MODULE_GUIDELINES.md`, and `Makefile` in my local directory, this might produce output like:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3      
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3   
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3      
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3    
open("/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3        
openat(AT_FDCWD, "Makefile", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY) = 3               
openat(AT_FDCWD, "MANIFEST.in", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY) = 3            
openat(AT_FDCWD, "MODULE_GUIDELINES.md", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY) = 3   
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can see here both the shared libraries opened when running `grep` as well as the files that were opened by `grep` itself.

You can read more in the [strace man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).

Comment: Indeed. I am using Mac OS X so I will have to give DTrace a try. Thanks for your answer.